# Why does Latex does not complile flalign enviroment after a certain point?

Tags: enumerate, compiling, flalign

I would like to bring rewrite in an flalign enviroment what I did here with enumerate. The reason for this is to have a numbering and to label this equation.

However, when I try to do it after five or six lines I get a blank page or a compile failure.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[sans,nouppercase]{frontespizio}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand*\underdot[1]{%
  \underaccent{\dot}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}
\setstackgap{L}{.7\baselineskip}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\newbox\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnCornerHgt
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$\ulcorner$}
\global\gnCornerHgt=\ht\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnArgHgt
\def\Godelnum #1{%
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$#1$}%
\gnArgHgt=\ht\gnBoxA%
\ifnum     \gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt \gnArgHgt=0pt%
\else \advance \gnArgHgt by -\gnCornerHgt%
\fi \raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\ulcorner$} \box\gnBoxA %
\raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\urcorner$}}
\newbox\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnCornerHgt
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$\ulcorner$}
\global\gnCornerHgt=\ht\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnArgHgt
\def\Godelnum #1{%
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$#1$}%
\gnArgHgt=\ht\gnBoxA%
\ifnum     \gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt \gnArgHgt=0pt%
\else \advance \gnArgHgt by -\gnCornerHgt%
\fi \raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\ulcorner$} \box\gnBoxA %
\raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\urcorner$}}



\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item[$\mathsf{PAT}\vdash\vartheta(x)\leftrightarrow$]$\exists s \exists t(x=(s\d{=}t) \wedge s^{\circ} = t^{\circ}) \lor $
 \item[] $\exists s \exists t(x=(\d{\neg}s\d{=}t)\wedge s^{\circ} \neq t^{\circ})\lor$
 \item[]$\exists y (Sent_{T}(y)\wedge x=(\d{\neg}\d{\neg}y)\wedge T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\Dot{y})})\lor$
 \item[]$ \exists y \exists z(Sent_{T}(y\d{\wedge}z)\wedge x = (y\d{\wedge}z)\lor (T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\dot{y})}\wedge T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\Dot{z})}))\lor$
 \item[]$\exists y \exists z(Sent_{T}(y \d{\wedge}z)\wedge x =(\d{\neg}(y\d{\wedge}z))\wedge(T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\Dot{y})}\lor T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\Dot{z})}))\lor$
 \item[]$\exists y \exists z(Sent_{T}(y\d{\lor}z)\wedge x = (y \d{\lor}z)\wedge(T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\Dot{y})}\lor T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\Dot{z})}))\lor$
 
 
 \item[]$\exists y \exists z(Sent_{T}(y\d{\lor}z)\wedge x=(\d{\neg}(y \d{\lor}z))\wedge (T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\Dot{y})}\wedge T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\Dot{z})}))\lor$
 \item[]$\exists v \exists y(Sent_{T}(\d{\forall}vy) \wedge x=(\d{\forall}vy)\wedge \forall T\Godelnum{\vartheta(y(t/v))})\lor$
 \item[]$\exists v \exists y(Sent_{T}(\d{\forall}vy) \wedge x = (\d{\neg}\d{\forall}vy)\wedge \exists t T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}y(t/v))})\lor$
 \item[]$\exists v \exists y(Sent_{T}(\d{\exists}vy)\wedge x = (\d{\exists}vy)\wedge \exists t T\Godelnum{\vartheta(y(t/v))})\lor$

 \item[]$\exists v \exists y(Sent_{T}(\d{\exists}vy)\wedge x=(\d{\neg}\d{\exists}vy)\wedge\forall t T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}y(t/v))})\lor$
 \item[]$\exists t(x=(\underdot{T}t)\wedge T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\underdot{t})})\lor$
 \item[]$\exists t(x=(\d{\neg}\underdot{T}t)\wedge(T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\underdot{t})}\lor \neg Sent_{T}(t^{\circ})))$
    
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is how I am trying to do it, as I said it works for a few lines but I get an error when I try to put the whole code.

```
\begin{flalign}
 \mathsf{PAT}\vdash\vartheta(x)  \leftrightarrow & \exists s \exists t(x=(s\d{=}t) \wedge s^{\circ} = t^{\circ}) \lor\\
& \exists s \exists t(x=(\d{\neg}s\d{=}t)\wedge s^{\circ} \neq t^{\circ})\lor \\
& \exists y (Sent_{T}(y)\wedge x=(\d{\neg}\d{\neg}y)\wedge T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\Dot{y})})\lor \\
& \exists y \exists z(Sent_{T}(y\d{\wedge}z)\wedge x = (y\d{\wedge}z)\lor T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\dot{y})}\wedge T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\Dot{z})}\lor \\
& \exists y \exists z(Sent_{T}(y \d{\wedge}z)\wedge x =(\d{\neg}(y\d{\wedge}z))\wedge(T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\Dot{y})}\lor T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\Dot{z})}))\lor \\
& \exists y \exists z(Sent_{T}(y\d{\lor}z)\wedge x = (y \d{\lor}z)\wedge(T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\Dot{y})}\lor T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\Dot{z})}))\lor \\
& \exists y \exists z(Sent_{T}(y\d{\lor}z)\wedge x=(\d{\neg}(y \d{\lor}z))\wedge T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\Dot{y})}\wedge T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\Dot{z})})\lor \\
& \exists v \exists y(Sent_{T}(\d{\forall}vy) \wedge x=(\d{\forall}vy)\wedge \forall T\Godelnum{\vartheta(y(t/v))})\lor \\
& \exists v \exists y(Sent_{T}(\d{\forall}vy) \wedge x = (\d{\neg}\d{\forall}vy)\wedge \exists t T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}y(t/v))})\lor \\
& \exists v \exists y(Sent_{T}(\d{\exists}vy)\wedge x = (\d{\exists}vy)\wedge \exists t T\Godelnum{\vartheta(y(t/v))})\lor \\
& \exists v \exists y(Sent_{T}(\d{\exists}vy)\wedge x=(\d{\neg}\d{\exists}vy)\wedge\forall t T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}y(t/v))})\lor \\
& \exists t(x=(\underdot{T}t)\wedge T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\underdot{t})})\lor \\
& \exists t(x=(\d{\neg}\underdot{T}t)\wedge(T\Godelnum{\vartheta(\d{\neg}\underdot{t})}\lor \neg Sent_{T}(t^{\circ})))


\end{flalign}
```

Comment: You can't have blank lines in `flalign`.

Comment: I am not looking for the same spacing as in the image. I just want to put those formula in a flalign enviorment.